# Want to add target=_blank to a href in php1

Tags: php, html, href

I want to add target=_blank to this php-code:

Click me

I have tried almost all possible syntax, but they all fails. The code it self works.

Comment: add some code to understand what is problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

```
<?php echo "<a href='#' target='_blank'>Click me</a>"; ?>
```